# Consequences of dropping the year in vanilla TexLive installation

Tags: texlive

Based on the first installation of TexLive, I saved my profile file, which I now use to reinstall each new version of TexLive.

In that profile file, now I have the following:

```
selected_scheme scheme-custom
TEXDIR /home/myusername/texlive/2023
TEXMFCONFIG ~/.texlive2023/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME ~/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /home/myusername/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /home/myusername/texlive/2023/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /home/myusername/texlive/2023/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive2023/texmf-var

...

tlpdbopt_sys_bin /home/myusername/texlive/2023/bin
tlpdbopt_sys_info /home/myusername/texlive/2023/info
tlpdbopt_sys_man /home/myusername/texlive/2023/man
```

I am not interested in reiterating the discussion about installing TexLive as a regular user, but I am interested in the following:

If I change the path in the following way, i.e. dropping the year:

```
TEXDIR /home/myusername/texlive
TEXMFCONFIG ~/.texlive/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME ~/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /home/myusername/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /home/myusername/texlive/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /home/myusername/texlive/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive/texmf-var

...

tlpdbopt_sys_bin /home/myusername/texlive/bin
tlpdbopt_sys_info /home/myusername/texlive/info
tlpdbopt_sys_man /home/myusername/texlive/man
```

**Question:**
Using `tlmgr update --all --self` each time, what are the consequences of doing this when TexLive is frozen and the new 2024 version is ready to be installed?

Comment: I do something else. In the `texlive` dir I make a softlink called `current` pointing to the year I want. Then I just add `path/texlive/current/stuff` to my paths. And then next time a new texlive comes along, I just move the softlink.

Comment: As for consequences, `tlmgr` does not know about the year in the path. It does not care. The year is known in its configuration. Otherwise one would not be able to choose your own location for TeXLive during the installation

Comment: The idea was when TexLive 2024 will be available if I `tlmgr update --all --self` will update the current `~/texlive` folder without installing the new version.

Comment: As already mentioned in the answer that is generally not recommended. Especially also because over the next few years there are expected to be some big changes to the LaTeX format (the tagging project ect), so having the option to go back to an older installation is rather important.

Comment: I'd avoid such “simplification”. You lose much and gain little. When installing TeX Live on a GNU/Linux system, I just have to replace a soft link so it points to the binary directory for current year. The soft link is used in the initialization files for setting the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using tlmgr update --all --self each time, what are the consequences of doing this when TexLive is frozen and the new 2024 version is ready to be installed?

Using the year in the path is purely a convention.  So, you can have a working set-up as you described.  Then what will happen is that at some point `tlmgr update --all` will report `TL2023` is frozen and will no longer receive updates.

At this stage there is (or has been at least, don't know if still will be) a [non-recommended way to upgrade](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) which you can apply when `TL2024` gets released (the instructions are currently naturally for `TL2022` to `TL2023` transition).  As your installation directory does not contain `2023` you have to adapt the description of steps there.  In particular make a backup copy of the whole thing so that you can recover in case something goes wrong.  As you will keep the same directory name, you will not have to adjust PATH and `cd` to a new directory before using the install script.  So you download the install script and use it in the special way described in the instructions.  I strongly recommend you do a backup copy of the whole thing first.  Also do not attempt this in the pre-test period, as the updating script may not yet be ready and using it can break your installation.  In this way you can have a "rolling" install of TeXLive.  But this is *not* the officially supported way.  And the [upgrade instructions](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) add that there is no analogous way on Windows, this is on Unixen (macos included, if you don't need to update the MacTeX provided extras) only.